# Ruby - array in mysql execute

Tags: mysql, ruby, parameter-passing, statements

I'm trying to get the code below to work. I want to pass an array to mysql execute, so I can reuse the code to different query's.

```
# This will work, but want to pass a array in execute
st = con.prepare('SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id=? AND x=? AND y=?')
st.execute('123', '2', '2')



# my code
require 'mysql'

def query(str, arr)
  begin
      con = Mysql.new 'host', 'user', 'pass', 'db'

      st = con.prepare(str)
      test = arr.map {|str| "\"#{str}\""}.join(',')
      st.execute(test) 

  rescue Mysql::Error => e
      puts "#{e.errno} #{e.error}"

  ensure
      con.close if con
  end
end


arr = ['123', '2', '2']
data = query('SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id=? AND x=? AND y=?', arr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the mysql gem, but I think `st.execute(*arr)` should work:

```
def query(str, arr)
  begin
     connection = Mysql.new('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db')
     statement  = connection.prepare(str)
     statement.execute(*arr) 
  rescue Mysql::Error => e
    puts e.message
  ensure
    connection.close if connection
  end
end
```

Comment: execute(*arr) did the trick. just execute(arr) gave this error: execute: param_count(4) != number of argument(1)